# Compute the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^x}{x^b}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm calculating for the following limit, and would greatly appreciate the communities support and feedback on my approach.

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^x}{x^b}$

I know that, $a^x = e^{x\log(a)}$ and $x^b = e^{b\log(x)}$

So then I get:

$$\frac{e^{x\log(a)}}{e^{b\log(x)}}=\frac{e^{\lim_{x \to +\infty}x\log(a)}}{e^{\lim_{x \to +\infty}b\log(x)}}$$

I know that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \log(x) = +\infty$ perhaps this is also the same when $x \log(x)$?

Hence $\frac{e^{\lim_{x \to +\infty}x\log(a)}}{e^{\lim_{x \to +\infty}b\log(x)}}=+\infty$

Comment: $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ is an indetermination...

Comment: What are the ranges of $a,b$?

Comment: @Meilton Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that

$$\frac{a^x}{x^b}=e^{\log(a)x\left(1-\frac{b\log(x)}{\log(a)x}\right)}$$

What is the limit of $1-\frac{b\log(x)}{\log(a)x}$?

Be careful to note that for $a>1$, $\log(a)>0$ while for $0<a<1$, $\log(a)<0$.  The case $a=0$ is trivial.

Comment: @Meilton Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit. ;-)